# Laravel route model binding with Interfaces instead of models

Tags: php, laravel

### Update

I really don't know what happened, but it works. I didn't change anything except some refactoring, but clearly, I fixed something that I'm not aware of. Currently, both of these lines in middleware do the job. I choose to use the first one:

```
Route::model($this->var($model), $contract);
Route::model($this->var($model), $model);
```

I think this structure can help someone how wants to achieve the same thing.

### Original Question

I'm creating a multitenant app, and both landlord and tenant apps use the same models in some cases. For example: User.

```php
// The models:


namespace App\Models;

class User extends Model { ... }



namespace Landlord\Models;

class User extends BaseUser implements UserInterface { ... }



namespace Tenant\Models;

class User extends BaseUser implements UserInterface { ... }
```

Then I create a middleware to handle bindings.

```php
class ModelBindingMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        foreach (config('common_models') as $baseModel) {

            // convert model's namespace based on request host
            // from App\Models\User to Landlord\Models\User or Tenant...
            $model = $this->model($baseModel); 
            
            // convert App\Models\User to App\Contracts\UserInterface
            $contract= $this->contract($baseModel); 

            // I tried all 3 of those options
            Route::bind($this->var($model), fn ($v) => $model::find($v));
            Route::model($this->var($model), $contract);
            Route::model($this->var($model), $model);


            // And bind to service container
            app()->bind($contract, $model);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

```php
namespace App\Controllers;

class UserController
{
    public function show(UserInterface $user)
    {
        // route for this example is landlord.test/users/1
        // Both in dd() return the same class: Landlord\Models\User
        // but $user is an empty instance and I want to make this work.

        dd($user, Users::query('User')->find(1));

        // Users::query($model) is a facade method that returns
        // Landlord\Models\User::query() or Tenant...
    }
}
```

```php
Route::get('users/{user}', [UserController::class, 'show']);
```

Does anyone have any idea how can I use `UserInterface` instead of `User` model here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you registering the middleware? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#registering-middleware . Also, here's a decent article from Freek @spatie: https://freek.dev/453-route-model-binding-using-middleware where he does a similar thing

Comment: there is a middleware that does the route model bindings, but it calls the Router to do most of the work .. you would need to change the way those calls work to be able to adjust this

Comment: @CornelRaiu middleware does its job. I know that UserInterface returns Landlord\Models\User which is $user in controller. The problem is it's empty instance, no data from users table.